# flex datagrid itemRenderer with different states

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a datagrid with allowMultipleSelection="true" & itemRenderer as my custom component. The custom component have 2 states "NORMAL" & "EXPANDED".

Now on row selection the renderer should change its state from NORMAL to EXPANDED state. And if I am selecting multiple rows then all the selected rows should be in EXPANDED state.

As soon as the selection goes the renderer should retain its NORMAL state.

Comment: so what have you done so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried with itemClick event, it is changing the state of clicked item but I am unable to regain the NORMAL state on getting deselected.
As I didn't find any select/deselect events in datagrid.
Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: Since you can trap the click couldn't you store a 'toggled / untoggled' state for each row?